# RDLC Subreport Parameters Not Working as Expected

Tags: c#, reporting, rdlc, subreport

I have an RDLC report, which displays basic information about financial transactions, and within that report I have a subreport to display the details for these transactions.

I'm having some trouble getting parameters to pass between the main and subreport.  The subreport accepts one parameter: `TransactionID`.  When I set the main report to send the actual value of `TransactionID` for each row, the `SubreportProcessing` event handler never fires, and when I try to expand the subreport, a message about a null reference exception appears in the debug output, but I cannot catch this exception to find out exactly *what* is null.  Along with the null reference exception, the subreport displays:

> Error: Subreport could not be shown

As a test, I tried to hard-code the value `0` for `TransactionID`, and then the `SubreportProcessing` event fired for every row, but with obviously incorrect results.  This leads me to suspect that the `TransactionID` value in the rows of the main report is somehow coming up `null` when it tries to use it as a parameter, but I don't understand how that could be happening, or how to fix it.

Edit:
Since the literal value `0` worked, I dedcided to try one of the `TransactionID` values from the actual report (`2652791667`), and found that it failed under those conditions as well.  Noting that the given value exceeds the range of an `Int32`, I tried a smaller number, which worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Int32` issue was the answer.  I tried changing the subreport's `TransactionID` parameter to Text, but it apparently couldn't automatically convert the numeric value of `TransactionID` from the main report data to a string.

In the end, I added a field to my dataset, called `TransactionIDStr`, and populated it with `TransactionID.ToString()`, and it now functions flawlessly.